# Data into multiple groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to group the data into multiple groups.

For example as shown below.

**Example**:

I have a table test:

```
create table test
(
 column1 varchar(10),
 column2 varchar(10)
)
```

Inserting some data:

```
insert into test values('X','Y');
insert into test values('Y','Z');
insert into test values('X','A');
insert into test values('O','P');
insert into test values('N','M');
insert into test values('S','T');
insert into test values('W','O');
insert into test values('A','K');
insert into test values('E','N');
```

Now I have this data:

```
select * from test;

column1    column2
------------------
   X         Y
   Y         Z
   X         A
   O         P
   N         M
   S         T
   W         O
   A         K
   E         N
```

In the above data i have the values for which i have to group them which are belongs to each other:
  `(X-Y,Y-Z,X-A,A-K)` and `(O-P,W-O)` and `(N-M,E-N)`.

For these values I have to make a groups namely `group 1,2,3`.

Group 1: `(X-Y,Y-Z,X-A,A-K)`
Group 2: `(O-P,W-O)`
Group 3: `(N-M,E-N)`

And I want to show the table in the following format:

**Result**:

```
Group Number   column1    column2
--------------------------------
     1            X         Y
     1            Y         Z
     1            X         A
     2            O         P
     3            N         M
     0            S         T
     2            W         O
     1            A         K
     3            E         N
```

Comment: @Umair, Really not getting. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE (column1 + column2)
        WHEN 'XY' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'YZ' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'XA' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'AK' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'OP' THEN '2'
        WHEN 'WO' THEN '2'
        WHEN 'NM' THEN '3'
        WHEN 'EN' THEN '3'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS [Group Number],
    column1,
    column2
FROM test
--ORDER BY [Group Number]
```

OR...

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN (column1 + column2) IN ('XY', 'YZ', 'XA', 'AK') THEN '1'
        WHEN (column1 + column2) IN ('OP', 'WO') THEN '2'
        WHEN (column1 + column2) IN ('NM', 'EN') THEN '3'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS [Group Number],
    column1,
    column2
FROM test
```

Comment: I think he dont want an ORDER BY

Comment: you also have created the combinations manually... but I think there will not be such specific and limited combinations in actual DB. He has provided some data from his table, not all.

Comment: @user2315555, when we need custom things to be implemented, we need to specify those things somewhere, right? Do u think there is any way sql server finds to save custom grouping?

Comment: I am unaware of what you mean by "custom things" or "custom groupings" in SQL Server.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (GroupNumber int,column1 VARCHAR(1),column2 VARCHAR(1))  
INSERT INTO @table VALUES 
(1,'X','Y'),(1,'Y','Z'),(1,'X','A'),(1,'A','K'),
(2,'O','P'),(1,'W','O'),
(3,'N','M'),(3,'E','N')

SELECT      ISNULL(LU.GroupNumber,0) GroupNumber,
            T.column1,
            T.column2
FROM        test T
LEFT JOIN   @table LU 
            ON  T.column1 = LU.column1 
            AND T.column2 = LU.column2
```

Comment: @Jithin Shaji, I don't want to insert group number and group manually into temp table, I have to calculate that.

Comment: your source table is test. in paraller cant you declare a @table with just 8 records?, other wise u will have to write a big CASE statement.
by using a temp table , u have the flexibility to add more groups as well.

Comment: @Jithin Shaji, Obviously! But I don't want to do it this way. I want to calculate the groups.